# Cannot run "git" with exec.Command()

Tags: git, go

I want to run `exec.Command("git", "config", "--global", "user.name")` and read the output.

On windows the word `"git"` translates to the git path (`C:\Program Files\...\git.exe`). Then it tries to run `C:\Program` (which is not a path to an executable).

I have tried escaping the space, I have tried to add parentheses around the path, or only around the space and escape them. Nothing worked.

```
arg0 := "config"
arg1 := "--global"
arg2 := "\"user.name\""
bcmd := exec.Command("git", arg0, arg1, arg2)
var stdout bytes.Buffer
bcmd.Stdout = &stdout
err := bcmd.Run()
```

I have tried adding parentheses and it did not help.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What error did you get?

Comment: on my mac, i change `arg2 := "\"user.name\""` to `arg2 := "user.name"`

Comment: `arg2` is definitely wrong, it shouldn't have quotes inside the parameter value.

Comment: Thank you all, the error it was typing out made it seem like the problem was in the word git and path to the git executable. But arg2 was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use quotes for `arg2`. As for *reading the output* it depends what you understand by *reading*. The output will be written to the buffer which is `stdout` in your case. You can obtain the bytes of the output using `stdout.Bytes()` and if you want the actual `string` (which I assume you actually want) you can just cast to `string` using `string(stdout.Bytes())`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    bcmd := exec.Command("git", "config", "--global", "user.name")
    var stdout bytes.Buffer
    bcmd.Stdout = &stdout
    err := bcmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf(string(stdout.Bytes()))
}
```

There also is another simpler way to do the same thing using `Output()`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    outputBytes, err := exec.Command("git", "config", "--global", "user.name").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf(string(outputBytes))
}
```

Both will print your git username.